# How can I get Foreign Key with doctrine on ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I have two tables one called Country (id,name) other Area (id,name,idFCountry)

I do this in my controller:

```
$area = new Area();
$area->setNumarea($numarea);
$area->setNamearea($namearea);
$area->setIdfkcountry($idFCountry);
```

I get this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Synchro\Entity\area::setIdfkcountry() must be an instance of
>   Synchro\Entity\Country

How can I resolve this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess $idFCountry is not an object, probably (based on the variable name) you are trying to pass a string or integer.

Seems you are using Zend, so an easy way to solve this is getting the object based on the country id, assuming $idFCountry is an string containing the id:

```
$repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Synchro\Entity\Country');
$countryObject = findOneBy(array('idcountry' =>$idFCountry));

$area->setIdfkcountry($countryObject);
```

Comment: ,Thanks i do that but i have this Error The identifier idcountry is missing for a query of Synchro\Entity\Country Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try $countryObject = $repository->findBy(array('idcountry' =>$idFCountry)); instead of the find method?